# Use dict.get() to look for specified names and print their value if present

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, geojson

I have a GeoJSON in below format:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "uuid": "___",
            "type": "road",
            "length": "10m",
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [__________],
                [__________],
                [__________]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

I have written the below python script to try and read out the type of GeoJSON, known in this file as `road`.

```
def process_incoming_file(self, bucket, key, event):
    bulk_data = []

    try:
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        decoded_content = json.loads(obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
        print(decoded_content)

        if decoded_content.get('type') == "FeatureCollection":

            for (idx, obj) in enumerate(decoded_content['features']):
                bulk_item = {}

                props = obj.get('properties')

                name = obj['properties'].get('name') or 'NULL'
                print(name)

                keys = [title.lower() for title in props]
                print('keys', keys)

                type = obj['properties'].get('type', 'road')
                print(obj['properties'].get('road'))
```

My issue is that in other GeoJSON files, type could be called something other than `formofway`.

How do I write a statement to look for different names it could come under, e.g.

```
type = obj['properties'].get('type', 'road', 'othername', 'something')
```

and if one of those names is present within the properties part of the GeoJSON then print its associated value? e.g. `road`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest calls to `get()`

```
prop = obj['properties']
type = prop.get('type', prop.get('formofway', prop.get('othername', prop.get('something'))))
```

But this will get very deep if there are lots of possibilities. You can use a loop instead.

```
type_props = ['type', 'formofway', 'othername', 'something']
for prop in type_props:
    if prop in obj['properties']:
        type = obj['properties'][prop]
        break
```